# How do I produce a large number of items in the assembler?

Tags: space-engineers

How can I, for example, produce 100 computers without clicking 100 times? I tried with the right mouse button and dragging from one inventory to the other and it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To speed things up a little, Ctrl+Click will add 10 of the selected item to the queue. Similarly, Shift+Click will add 100 of the selected item. This can save a lot of repetitive clicking when queuing up large numbers of components.

To produce a specific amount for example 15 does not seem to be a possibility.